# Is there a public database of mutex names that are associated with malware?

Tags: penetration-test, malware, detection

I remember seeing something like this a while back, and it'd be incredibly useful for a project I'm working on. Essentially there was a list of mutex names, with a list of malware identifiers (e.g. *W32/ZeusTroj*) that are associated with each. Unfortunately I can't find it anywhere, and can't remember the name of the project.

Right now I'd settle for just the mutex names alone, but if anyone knows of any projects that include this data it'd be extremely useful!

Comment: ThreatMiner lets you search their database by mutex name (e.g., [this search](https://www.threatminer.org/mutex.php?q=UVhVXmJpX2Ax)), and map from mutex name to malware name.  So, this means they have mutex names and malware names in their dataset, and if you could get access to their dataset, you could build a reverse mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ThreatExpert reports](http://www.threatexpert.com/reports.aspx) include mutex names, when applicable (see e.g. at the end of [this report](http://www.threatexpert.com/report.aspx?md5=85d5772203db174ab9d7822987ab0e93)). I am not sure they provide the data in a convenient format, though.